# How to use python to solve a combination problem?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, combinations

I want to solve a combination problem. Given a list of variables, I want to get all the polynomial items with a given order consisting of these variables. For example, for a given list of numbers `[x1, x2, x3]` and an order of 2, the function should return a list of `[x1^2, x1*x2, x1*x3, x2^2, x2*x3, x3^2]`; for a given list of numbers `[x1, x2]` and an order of 3, the function should return a list of `[x1^3, x1^2*x2, x1*x2^2, x2^3]`

If I use a for loop for the first example, the code will be like:

```
for i in range(given_order+1):
    for j in range(given_order+1-i):
        for k in range(given_order+1-j-i):
            list.append(x1^i*x2^j*x3^k)
```

However both the length of the given list and the given order are not fixed, so the number of for loops is uncertain. I tried to use recursion to solve it but failed. Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `for (a1, a2, ..., an) in itertools.permutations([x1, x2, ..., xn], r=n): list.append(a1 * a2 * ... * an)`?

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy. Thanks for your tips, itertools.combinations_with_replacement could solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `poly(t, order)` using [mathmatical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if input `t` is empty, stop iteration
2. (inductive) there is at least one `t`. if `order` is less than one, there is nothing left to expand, return the empty polynomial
3. (inductive) there is at least one `t` and `order` is at least one.

   - To include the first element in combinations, for all `p` in the sub-problem `(t, order - 1)`, prepend `t[0]` to `p` and yield
   - To generate all combinations without the first element, simply recur on the sub-problem `(t[1:], order)`

```py
def poly(t, order):
  if not t:
    return                        #1
  elif order < 1:
    yield ()                      #2
  else:
    for p in poly(t, order - 1):  #3
      yield (t[0], *p)
    yield from poly(t[1:], order)
```

With `order = 2` -

```py
for p in poly(('x', 'y', 'z'), 2):
  print("*".join(p))
```

```
x*x
x*y
x*z
y*y
y*z
z*z
```

With `order = 3` -

```py
for p in poly(('x', 'y', 'z'), 3):
  print("*".join(p))
```

```
x*x*x
x*x*y
x*x*z
x*y*y
x*y*z
x*z*z
y*y*y
y*y*z
y*z*z
z*z*z
```

Above we use `"*".join(p)` to format polynomials in readable way. You could however write a `format` function to convert `(x, x)` to `x^2` and `(x, z, z)` to `x*z^2` -

```py
def format(p):
  mem = dict()
  for x in p:
    mem[x] = mem[x] + 1 if x in mem else 1
  return "*".join(x if e == 1 else f"{x}^{e}" for (x,e) in mem.items())
```

```py
for p in poly(('x', 'y', 'z'), 3):
  print(format(p))
```

```
x^3
x^2*y
x^2*z
x*y^2
x*y*z
x*z^2
y^3
y^2*z
y*z^2
z^3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from @Mulan's very elegant answer, but there is already a built-in function that you can use instead:

```
import itertools

order = 3
var = ['x', 'y', 'z']

c = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(var, order)
for i in c:
   print(i)
```